# Amazon Instant on Xbox 360 via OS X

Tags: video, applications

Is there a way to view Amazon Instant Video content on the XBox 360 via OS X? The official solution on Amazon's site utilizes a Windows PC, which we don't have:
http://www.amazon.com/gp/video/ontv/xbox

Any other way?

I utilize an application called Connect360 (http://www.nullriver.com/products/connect360) to get media from my Mac to my Xbox 360. Would love to have a solution for watching Amazon Instant content on the 360 as well.

Answer (score 1):

Amazon now has an official Amazon Instant Video app for the Xbox 360. It is available under *Apps* from the Xbox 360 dashboard.